# Assigning color to the rectangle near legend items in wpf toolkit charting lineseries

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, legend, wpftoolkit

I am adding lineseries to a chart dynamically as follows.

```html
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>>> tempSeries in yieldSeries)
{
 LineSeries lineSeries = new LineSeries();
 lineSeries.DependentValuePath = "Value";
 lineSeries.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
 lineSeries.ItemsSource = tempSeries.Value;
 lineSeries.Title = tempSeries.Key;
 lineSeries.SetResourceReference(FrameworkElement.StyleProperty,"CommonLineSeries");
 lineSeries.Tag = Brushes.Red;
 
 lineSeries.Background = Brushes.Red;
 
 yieldTrendChart.Series.Add(lineSeries);
}
```

I wish to assign specific color in specific order for the lineseries to attain this I have added a style for the polyline as follows

```html
<Style x:Key="CommonLineSeries" TargetType="charting:LineSeries" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type charting:LineSeries}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:LineSeries">
                <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                    <Polyline Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" Stroke="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type charting:LineSeries}}}" Style="{TemplateBinding PolylineStyle}"/>
                </Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>        
</Style>
```

**Problem**
The color is successfully assigned to the lines in the graph **however the rectangle near the legend still shows the color assigned by .net randomly.**
**How shall I assign the same color to the rectangle as I have assigned it to the line??**

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit LegendItem Style to change color of legend rectangle.

**xaml**

```
Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"             
    xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:visualizationToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:datavis ="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    Title="Window1" Height="500" Width="700">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LineSeriesStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LineSeries}">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LineSeries}">
                    <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                        <Polyline Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" Stroke="{Binding Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type chartingToolkit:LineSeries}}}" />
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="mcChart"  >
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Tag="Green" x:Name="chart" DependentValuePath="Value"  IsSelectionEnabled="True" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource LineSeriesStyle1}">
            <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:LegendItem" >
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LegendItem}">
                                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                            <Rectangle Width="12" Height="12" Fill="{Binding ElementName=chart,Path=Tag}" StrokeThickness="1"  />
                                            <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=chart,Path=Tag}" FontSize="18" Margin="10"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle>
        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

**c#**

```
namespace WpfApplication8
```

{

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadColumnChartData();
    }

    private void LoadColumnChartData()
    {
        ((LineSeries)mcChart.Series[0]).ItemsSource =
        new KeyValuePair<string, int>[]{
        new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Project Manager", 13),
        new KeyValuePair<string,int>("CEO", 23),};

    }
}
```

}

**Result**
[image]

**Update**

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LineSeriesStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LineSeries}">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type chartingToolkit:LineSeries}}}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LineSeries}">
                    <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                        <Polyline x:Name="polyline"  Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" Stroke="{Binding Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Name="lineChart">
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Name="chart1" Tag="Blue" Background="Green"  Style="{StaticResource LineSeriesStyle1}" Title="KW Gastats"  DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding [0]}" IsSelectionEnabled="True">
            <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LegendItem}" >
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LegendItem}">
                                <Border >
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                            <Rectangle Width="12" Height="12" Fill="{Binding ElementName=chart1,Path=Tag}"  Stroke="{Binding Background}" StrokeThickness="1"  />
                                            <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=chart1,Path=Tag}" FontSize="18" Margin="10"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle>
        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Name="chart2" Tag="Green"   Style="{StaticResource LineSeriesStyle1}" Title="Preu KW"   DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding [1]}" IsSelectionEnabled="True" >
            <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LegendItem}" >
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LegendItem}">
                                <Border >
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                            <Rectangle Width="12" Height="12" Fill="{Binding ElementName=chart2,Path=Tag}"   StrokeThickness="1"  />
                                            <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=chart2,Path=Tag}" FontSize="18" Margin="10"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle>
        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

**c# Code**

```
InitializeComponent();

        List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> llistaGastats = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>();
        llistaGastats.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(DateTime.Now, 100));
        llistaGastats.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1), 200));
        List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> llistaPreu = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>();
        llistaPreu.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(DateTime.Now, 300));
        llistaPreu.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1), 300));
        var dataSourceList = new List<List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>>();
        dataSourceList.Add(llistaGastats);
        dataSourceList.Add(llistaPreu);
        lineChart.DataContext = dataSourceList;
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Hi Heena. Thanks for replying. How can I acheive this via code since I have to add several lineseries dynamically.

Comment: I see you have added two lineseries in the xaml and updated the datacontext with two keyvalue pair items. In my case the number of lineseries is not known before but is determined at runtime. Will the code work if I add more than two items to the datacontext Heena? Thankyou for your quick reply and help :)